# How can I generate classification report by removing this error?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to **generate classification** report of dataset **movie_reviews** from corpus which has already target names **[pos , neg]**. but found an **error**.

**Code:**

```
movie_train_clf = Pipeline([('vect',CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),('clas',BernoulliNB(fit_prior=True))])

movie_train_clas = movie_train_clf.fit(movie_train.data ,movie_train.target)

 predict = movie_train_clas.predict(movie_train.data)
 np.mean(predict==movie_train.target)
```

Now I use classification report

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(predict, movie_train_clas,target_names==target_names))
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array.
```

please help me with correct syntax.

Comment: You have a typo `target_names==target_names`; use only one `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code:

1) You have the wrong order of arguments in `classification_report`. As per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html):

```
classification_report(y_true, y_pred, ...
```

First argument is the true labels and second one is the predicted labels.

2) You are using `movie_train_clas` in the place of true labels. `movie_train_clas` as per your code is the return value of `movie_train_clf.fit()`, so its the `movie_train_clf` itself. `fit()` returns itself, so you cannot use that in place of ground truth labels.

3) As @AmiTavory spotted, the current error is due to comparison operator `(==)` used in place of assignment `(=)`. The correct call to `classification_report` should be:

```
classification_report(movie_train.target, predict, target_names=target_names)
```